# Best way for drag and drop dashboards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dashboard

Is there any jquery plugin for creating iGoogle style dashboard? So basically drag n drop style etc.

Possibly a way to save the location of the widgets into a database in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you locked into jQuery?

If you are not you should consider Dojo.

## Demo Drag and Drop Content panes

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.0b2/dojo-release-1.7.0b2/dojox/layout/tests/test_GridContainer.html

and

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.0b2/dojo-release-1.7.0b2/dojox/layout/tests/test_GridContainerColWidths.html

Answer (score 3):

`jquery ui` support drag and drop.U should not find exact plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [gridster library](http://gridster.net/)